# mysql select sum if value equal set sum to 0

Tags: mysql, sum

I am developing wms software, I write SQL to calculate items stock in warehouse. in the table I record out and in stock values if go out then negative value if receive in the warehouse item value is positive. In the same table I record inventory control too. So, I need SQLquery with sum all items stock and if have inventory control with same id of items, then if found SUM expression an inventory control row , The SUM expression need to equal with inventory control value and the resume summing.

So when SUM expression run into control row, I need to sum from the latest control to a defined date

information:
-- Server version: 8.0.18
-- PHP Version: 7.3.11

Create table :

> 

```
CREATE TABLE `magacin_zalihe` (
  `magacin_zalihe_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_magacin` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_materijali_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_materijali_sifra` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_materijali_naziv` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_materijali_kolicina` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_materijali_tip` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_materijali_tip2` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_materijali_mera` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_materijali_pakovanje` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_materijali_paleta` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_materijali_tezina` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_materijali_opis` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_magacioner` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_datum` date NOT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_narudzba` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_vrsta` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_kor_modif` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `magacin_zalihe_dat_modif` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

INSERT:

> 

```
INSERT INTO `magacin_zalihe` (`magacin_zalihe_id`, `magacin_zalihe_magacin`, `magacin_zalihe_materijali_id`, `magacin_zalihe_materijali_sifra`, `magacin_zalihe_materijali_naziv`, `magacin_zalihe_materijali_kolicina`, `magacin_zalihe_materijali_tip`, `magacin_zalihe_materijali_tip2`, `magacin_zalihe_materijali_mera`, `magacin_zalihe_materijali_pakovanje`, `magacin_zalihe_materijali_paleta`, `magacin_zalihe_materijali_tezina`, `magacin_zalihe_materijali_opis`, `magacin_zalihe_magacioner`, `magacin_zalihe_datum`, `magacin_zalihe_narudzba`, `magacin_zalihe_vrsta`, `magacin_zalihe_kor_modif`, `magacin_zalihe_dat_modif`) VALUES
(24, '1000', 132, '1110212612001', 'POLYSTICK IR-XE 36\" IT GRANULAR', '200.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '18.28', '20.00', '23.50', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-20', '', 'utovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-20 12:26:50'),
(25, '1000', 132, '1110212612001', 'POLYSTICK IR-XE 36\" IT GRANULAR', '250.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '18.28', '20.00', '23.50', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-20', '', 'utovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-20 12:26:50'),
(26, '1000', 132, '1110212612001', 'POLYSTICK IR-XE 36\" IT GRANULAR', '50.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '18.28', '20.00', '23.50', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-20', '', 'utovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-20 12:26:50'),
(27, '1000', 120, '1124314522021', 'POLIFLEX MINERAL P4,5', '-50.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '10.00', '23.00', '43.00', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-19', '', 'istovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21 05:56:59'),
(28, '1000', 132, '1110212612001', 'POLYSTICK IR-XE 36\" IT GRANULAR', '-25.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '18.28', '20.00', '23.50', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-19', '', 'istovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21 05:56:59'),
(29, '1000', 120, '1124314522021', 'POLIFLEX MINERAL P4,5', '100.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '10.00', '23.00', '43.00', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21', '', 'utovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21 08:03:28'),
(30, '1000', 120, '1124314522021', 'POLIFLEX MINERAL P4,5', '50.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '10.00', '23.00', '43.00', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-22', '', 'utovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21 08:05:10'),
(31, '1000', 120, '1124314522021', 'POLIFLEX MINERAL P4,5', '-100.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '10.00', '23.00', '43.00', '', 'dbence', '2021-05-19', '', 'istovar', 'dbence', '2021-05-21 08:25:14'),
(32, '1000', 120, '1124314522021', 'POLIFLEX MINERAL P4,5', '-80.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '10.00', '23.00', '43.00', '', 'dbence', '2021-05-21', '', 'istovar', 'dbence', '2021-05-21 08:31:13'),
(33, '1000', 52, '1122432441001', 'FIMAL A4/P', '-80.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '7.50', '20.00', '30.00', '', 'dbence', '2021-05-21', '', 'istovar', 'dbence', '2021-05-21 08:31:13'),
(34, '100', 125, '1124331321001', 'POLIFLEX PF4/S', '-100.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '10.00', '23.00', '44.00', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21', '', 'istovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21 08:57:27'),
(35, '1000', 121, '1123320261001', 'POLIFLEX P2', '-100.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '10.00', '30.00', '28.00', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21', '123456-2021', 'istovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21 12:09:24'),
(36, '1000', 132, '1110212612001', 'POLYSTICK IR-XE 36\" IT GRANULAR', '-400.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '18.28', '20.00', '23.50', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21', '223564-2021', 'istovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21 12:10:11'),
(37, '126', 4, '1111152042050', 'BÁZIS FATA CSUPASZ', '100.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '20.00', '64.00', '9.00', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21', '', 'utovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-21 12:51:55'),
(38, '100', 132, '1110212612001', 'POLYSTICK IR-XE 36\" IT GRANULAR', '10.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '18.28', '20.00', '23.50', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-26', '', 'utovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-31 10:18:58'),
(39, '100', 132, '1110212612001', 'POLYSTICK IR-XE 36\" IT GRANULAR', '-100.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '18.28', '20.00', '23.50', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-31', '', 'istovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-31 11:15:15'),
(40, '100', 24, '1110110002001', 'CARTABIT 350 1000M', '-150.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '1050.00', '1.00', '380.00', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-31', '', 'istovar', 'rsolar', '2021-05-31 11:16:30'),
(41, '100', 131, '1111311852001', 'POLYESTER 260 P11', '10.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '13.50', '36.00', '25.90', '', 'rsolar', '2021-06-23', '', 'utovar', 'rsolar', '2021-07-05 06:12:45'),
(42, '100', 132, '1110212612001', 'POLYSTICK IR-XE 36\" IT GRANULAR', '200.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '18.28', '20.00', '23.50', '', 'rsolar', '2021-06-23', 'INV - 2021-06-23', 'inventar', 'rsolar', '2021-07-05 06:12:45'),
(43, '100', 31, '1111141002007', 'CARTONFELTRO BITUMATO T350 2x1000M', '100.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '1050.00', '2.00', '370.00', '', 'rsolar', '2021-06-23', '', 'utovar', 'rsolar', '2021-07-05 06:12:45'),
(44, '100', 132, '1110212612001', 'POLYSTICK IR-XE 36\" IT GRANULAR', '-85.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '18.28', '20.00', '23.50', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-31', '', 'istovar', 'rsolar', '2021-07-05 06:13:07'),
(45, '100', 29, '1111141002005', 'CARTONFELTRO BITUMATO T 300 MARCEGAGLIA', '-1.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '1020.00', '1.00', '346.00', '', 'rsolar', '2021-05-31', '', 'istovar', 'rsolar', '2021-07-05 06:13:07'),
(46, '100', 120, '1124314522021', 'POLIFLEX MINERAL P4,5', '100.00', '2', '0', 'm2', '10.00', '23.00', '43.00', '', 'rsolar', '2021-07-05', '', 'utovar', 'rsolar', '2021-07-06 07:49:55');
```

First column as primary key and auto increment

needed output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5d6U.png)

in output needed 200 because the last row is control row and contains stock value of 200

my sql query:

```
SELECT SUM( t1.magacin_zalihe_materijali_kolicina ) AS temp,t1.* FROM magacin_zalihe AS t1 WHERE t1.magacin_zalihe_magacin='100' AND t1.magacin_zalihe_datum <= '2021-07-07' GROUP BY t1.magacin_zalihe_materijali_id
```

t1.magacin_zalihe_vrsta contains 1 row with value 'inventar'   this is control for warehouse. From this value needed to sum stock values. If have more than 1 row of control we needed to sum from latest control row.

my sql query to try but not works:

```
SELECT SUM(IF( t1.magacin_zalihe_vrsta != 'inventar', t1.magacin_zalihe_materijali_kolicina, @temp := t1.magacin_zalihe_materijali_kolicina )) AS temp,t1.* FROM magacin_zalihe AS t1 WHERE t1.magacin_zalihe_magacin='100' AND t1.magacin_zalihe_datum <= '2021-07-07' GROUP BY t1.magacin_zalihe_materijali_id
```

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: please provide sample data and (create + insert)script. Also, share the version of MySQL you are using. Also, share the output expected from sample.

Comment: i informations updated

Comment: Are you sure it should be string? t1.magacin_zalihe_magacin='100', maybe t1.magacin_zalihe_magacin=100 ?

Comment: Tried no effect, problem is how to set sum into 0 and add value from t1.magacin_zalihe_materijali_kolicina to and start sum. Or start sum from latest control row

Comment: Did you get any errors executing your command?

Comment: no query run without error

Comment: The last row by 'magacin_zalihe_id' is:
44 | 100 | 132  | 1110212612001 | POLYSTICK IR-XE 36" IT GRANULAR | -85.00 ...
So why 200?

Comment: because this row is control row, and before this row no matter what value is.

Comment: For clarification of your "inventar" Control Row.  Is this more of an ACTUAL inventory count?  Ex: through normal ins and outs of inventory, sometimes inventory "shrinks" or "expands" because 10 sold, but somehow 13 taken, or 20 come in, but 25 magically appeared.  Is the "inventar" an ACTUAL COUNT on hand to handle such +/- deflections of inventory?  So the inventar is actual count, then continue based on any +/- sold or receipt of new inventory.  Does this make sense and give correct context to inventar?

Comment: YES inventar is count hands stocks, and correct to the accurate stocks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF (
        p1.temp = 0,
        p1.magacin_zalihe_materijali_kolicina,
        p1.temp
    ) as temp_delta
FROM (
        SELECT SUM(
                IF(
                    t1.magacin_zalihe_vrsta != 'inventar',
                    0,
                    @temp := t1.magacin_zalihe_materijali_kolicina
                )
            ) AS temp,
            t1.*
        FROM magacin_zalihe AS t1
        WHERE t1.magacin_zalihe_magacin = '100'
            AND t1.magacin_zalihe_datum <= '2021-07-07'
        GROUP BY t1.magacin_zalihe_materijali_id
    ) as p1;
```

Comment: interesting... Thanks you